# Using define_method in Rails controller yields syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2. Below is my controller:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  class << self
    Shop::SHOP_TYPES.each do |shop_type|
      define_method "nearby_#{shop_type.pluralize}"
        @nearby_type = "#{shop_type.pluralize}"
      end
    end
  end

 ...
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base  
  SHOP_TYPES =  %w(cafe restaurant)
end
```

However, it gives me `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end` at the very last `end` belongs to `class ShopsController < ApplicationController`. I am trying to keep the code dry so that I don't have to manually code this:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def nearby_cafes
    @nearby_type = "cafes"
  end

  def nearby_restaurants
    @nearby_type = "restaurants"
  end

 ...
end
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`define_method` expects a block, you're missing the `do` on the line where you call `define_method`

Comment: I'm still fairly new to SO (regarding answering questions): why is it, that this simple answer to a simple problem gets more upvotes, than a more elaborate answer on a more complicated problem? Just coincidence, or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess some (including me) misses out the `do`. In the official API dock, it's not stated that we can actually use it as a block. But the first comment here http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method#762-define-method-with-parameters shows that we actually can. So your upvotes actually saved lots of people who missed out the `do`. Thanks again.